# How to compile and run c/c++ programs in Notepad++ using the WinAvr compiler

Tags: notepad++, winavr

I want to use notepad++ instead of programmer's notepad. How can i use the WinAvr compiler with notepad++??

Answer (score 1):

you can run any command line with the NppExec plugin (comes included).  It has fairly customizable scripts that you can setup to build projects.  I don't know anything about WinAvrcompiler but if it works in command-line then you should have no problem.  Just read the help files and it's help forums on sourceforge.